# what are the steps for republish the UWP app once again from my local machine?

Tags: uwp, store, windows-dev-center

One year ago I was published the UWP into windows store but suddenly Microsoft had changed the policies, that's why my app became unpublished from store by Microsoft. They were sent failed report which is having message like “**App Policies: 10.1.4 Active Presence**”

> **Notes To Developer**
>
> Apps must have an active presence in the Store. When determining
>   "active presence", Microsoft looks for factors including but not
>   limited to: acquisitions rate, update frequency, and adoption of new
>   platform features/capabilities.

So, can anyone suggest how to become my UWP app is available in the store? Or suggest me what are the steps for republish the app once again from my local machine.

Comment: It probably has to do with what your app does or doesn't do.  Can you share a bit of detail about your app?

Comment: @MichaelS.Scherotter, My app contains the feature like share your emergency location and also track your location etc....

Comment: try to increase version on targeted sdk

Comment: @pradeep Could you reply to the mail which informed you to ask for the details and consult for the solutions. I will also help you to consult the related team and you could refer to this [case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/871285cd-4e31-4577-954e-15ca3ddfedfd/app-was-unpublished-and-cannot-be-resubmited-app-policies-1014-active-presence?forum=wpsubmit) for the process.